# Change format of DateUtils.Format_ABBREV_RELATIVE

Tags: java, android

Currently I have code where it return me the difference between two point of time by using `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` but I want to change the text of the returned text. Currently this is what I get :

```
17 min ago
9 hr ago
13 hr ago
```

But what I really want is

```
17 minutes ago
9 hours ago
13 hours ago
```

this is my code :

```
CharSequence time = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(postTime,System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: try to pass FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE to the function.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Can you put that as the answer ? Again, thank you.

Comment: Added as a Answer. I didn't try but I think you can pass  null as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting in specific format you need to change the flag.

change `FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE` flag to `FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE`. This will returns character sequence in format you want.